# Cannot access a disposed object when calling callback method

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

I've a Duplex TCP IP WCF service. I'm currently unit-testing it.

In everyone of my test, I setup a new server, create a new ChannelFactory, create the InstanceContext and do the call.

Then I trigger the event(it's a Mock on the server side), and the server give me this exception when it tries to reach the client:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.

Important point, this happens ONLY when I run all the tests in a row(sequentially executed but in the same execution).

There is nothing special about my service:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
public interface IMyService{
    [OperationContract]
    void SomeVariousMethods();
} 

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void HandleMessageFromServer(String message);
}


[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MyService : IMyService{
    public MyService(ISomeServerComponent component){
        component.OnMessage += OnMessageReceived;
    }

    public void SomeVariousMethods(){
        //...
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, EventArgs<String> e){
        IMyServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();
        callBack.HandleMessageFromServer(e.Data);//Crash here
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm currently UnitTesting it(not exactly, I've a lot of this that has been extracted in some helpers:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTest:IMyServiceCallback{

    private Mock<ISomeServerComponent> _mock;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup(){
        //... Creating a mock for the ISomeServerComponent that the MyService receives
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSomeVariousMethods(){
        string serviceName = nameof(TestSomeVariousMethods);
        using(ServiceHost host = CreateServer(_mock.Object,serviceName)){
            using (IMyService service = CreateClient(serviceName, this)){
                service.SomeVariousMethods();
            }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCallback(){
        string serviceName = nameof(TestSomeVariousMethods);
        using(ServiceHost host = CreateServer(_mock.Object,serviceName)){
            using (IMyService service = CreateClient(serviceName, this)){
                _mock.TriggerCallBack();
                //Assert-that-the-flag-has-been-set
            }
        }
    }

    public void HandleMessageFromServer(String msg){
        //Flag that this method has been called
    }




    private ServiceHost CreateServer(ISomeServerComponent mock, string serviceName){
        UnityServiceHost serviceHost = new UnityServiceHost(m_container);//This extends ServiceHost to be able to inject some objects to my services
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int64.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", IPAddress.Any, 9999, serviceName));

        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMyService)), binding, uri);
        serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());

        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);
        return serviceHost;
    }

    private IMyService CreateClient(string serviceName, IMyServiceCallback callback){
        UnityServiceHost serviceHost = new UnityServiceHost(m_container);//This extends ServiceHost to be able to inject some objects to my services
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int64.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", IPAddress.Loopback, 9999, serviceName));


        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callBack);
        DuplexChannelFactory channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>(context, binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
        return channelFactory.CreateChannel()
    }
}
```

Funny part is that all of this works when I'm ONLY running `TestCallback` test, but if I run all the test of the class, it fails, like if the second time, the `InstanceContext` was not creating properly the callback.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: I have only just schemed through your code but when it comes to tcp you get object disposed exception especially when socket is not closed properly

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Well, I've put some breakpoint in all my dispose, everything is closed properly. I've the feeeling it try to reuse the same "transparent proxy" for the callback of the second unit tests(and when the second tests runs, the first InstanceContext has already been released

Comment: @Are the test running one after another or st the same time? If at the same time, since tcp is blocking, it would not be possible to bind to the same socket

Comment: @EmrahSüngü one after the other

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue. I feel a little bit stupid, but in fact, in the Service implementation, I was not unregistering from the `OnMessage` correctly, so when the event was triggered, the previous service instance were trying to communicate with the already closed client.

Comment: Glad you found it :)